# Clickhouse datetime comparison not working as expected

Tags: database, datetime, clickhouse

I am trying to compare the datetime, in clickhouse. But it's seems it's working in some wired way. 
I have a column in my table which I want to compare with (now(),'UTC'). 
If the value of datetime in that column is less then the (now(),'UTC') Time than I wanna select data from that record.

I have created the table like

`` create table my_table (`mytime` DateTime, `data' [type]) ENGINE= engine ``

I want the queue like 
`Select data from my_table where mytime < toDateTime(now(), 'UTC')`

Even if mytime > toDateTime(now(), 'UTC') it always considers mytime < toDateTime(now(), 'UTC')

Comment: toDateTime(now(), 'UTC') -- has no sense. now() -- is already in UTC. 
DateTime stored in table is a unixtime in UTC. 
DateTime('UTC') -- means convert to UTC when converting to String.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason behind this issue was in clickhouse, it takes DateTime and DateTime('UTC') as different objects, therefore the comparison between them does not work as expected. Since I wanted to make the comparison with (now(),'UTC'), I have to change the type of 
`mytime` as `DateTime ('UTC')`.

I have to change the table as

`` create table my_table (`mytime` DateTime ('UTC'), `data' [type]) ENGINE= engine ``

Answer (score 3):

It seems to me that something may up with the way you inserted data or your ClickHouse version has a bug.

The following example shows how to do what you are attempting in a way that works on my 19.15.4.10 server as expected to select only the earlier row.  Note the select sleep() to ensure now() invocations are different.

```
drop table if exists my_table;
create table my_table (mytime DateTime, data String) engine = Memory;
insert into my_table values(now(), 'a');
select sleep(1);
insert into my_table values(toDateTime('2020-01-01 00:00:00', 'UTC'), 'b');
select * from my_table where mytime < now();
select * from my_table where mytime < toDateTime(now(), 'UTC');
```

On my server it does not matter whether you select now() or convert it. I also tried the way you originally defined the table and that works too. Hence the thought that something is up with your data.